# HoloLens - Unity: moving project

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Hey I tried to switch version (unity 5.6.2 to unity 2017), The problem is that the cursor doesn't work anymore. If I create a new project then it works. I use canvas, and button, but the click doesn't work. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure you have EventSystems in your scene - canvas events won't work without it.

Comment: Yes I have it, i'm trying to fix my errors (error cs1061 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) and hope it will work